# Bing Map API vs Bing Map manual RouteRequest . Is the API inaccurate?

Tags: java, bing-api

I tried to test Bing Map API's accuracy  . I tried to find out the distance and driving time between `Chicago O'Hare International Airport` and `Chicago Midway Airport` . ***It appears that Bing Map API is completely inaccurate . I double and triple checked it manually with bing maps . Here is the complete code***

```
import net.virtualearth.dev.webservices.v1.common.Credentials;
import net.virtualearth.dev.webservices.v1.common.Location;
import net.virtualearth.dev.webservices.v1.route.BasicHttpBinding_IRouteServiceStub;
import net.virtualearth.dev.webservices.v1.route.RouteRequest;
import net.virtualearth.dev.webservices.v1.route.RouteResponse;
import net.virtualearth.dev.webservices.v1.route.RouteResult;
import net.virtualearth.dev.webservices.v1.route.RouteServiceLocator;
import net.virtualearth.dev.webservices.v1.route.RouteSummary;
import net.virtualearth.dev.webservices.v1.route.Waypoint;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

         double [] address1Coordinate = {  41.97980880737305   ,   -87.88204193115234 } ; // Chicago O'Hare International Airport, IL  [I checked the coordinate . It is accurate ]
         double [] address2Coordinate = {  41.7872200012207    ,   -87.74160766601562 } ; // Chicago Midway Airport, IL  [I checked the coordinate . It is accurate ]

        BasicHttpBinding_IRouteServiceStub routeService = (BasicHttpBinding_IRouteServiceStub) (new RouteServiceLocator()).getBasicHttpBinding_IRouteService();

        RouteRequest request = new RouteRequest();
        Credentials creds = new Credentials();
        // I got my Bing map key from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx and entered it below : 
        creds.setApplicationId("This is my Bing App Key . . . ");
        request.setCredentials(creds);
        Waypoint[] waypoints = new Waypoint[2];
        waypoints[0] = new Waypoint();
        Location start = new Location();
        start.setLatitude(address1Coordinate[0]); 
        start.setLongitude(address1Coordinate[1]); 
        waypoints[0].setLocation(start);
        waypoints[1] = new Waypoint();
        Location end = new Location();
        end.setLatitude(address2Coordinate[0]); 
        end.setLongitude(address2Coordinate[1]) ; 
        waypoints[1].setLocation(end);
        request.setWaypoints(waypoints);

        RouteResponse response = routeService.calculateRoute(request);
        RouteResult result = response.getResult();

        RouteSummary routeSummary = result.getSummary();

        System.out.println( "Bing Distance : " + routeSummary.getDistance() + " miles ");   
        System.out.println( "Driving Time : " + routeSummary.getTimeInSeconds()/60 + " minutes ");

    }


}
```

[This is the link to the JARs](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/jars.zip)

---

The result that I got was

```
Bing Distance : 42.898 miles 
Driving Time : 34 minutes
```

**The above results are absolutely inaccurate** . [***I compared manually  the numbers with `Bing Map`  Click this link to see the difference***](http://www.bing.com/maps/#Y3A9NDEuODg1MDc4fi04Ny43NzQzNjYmbHZsPTExJnN0eT1yJnJ0cD1wb3MuNDEuOTc2ODEwXy04Ny45MDQ4MDBfQ2hpY2FnbyUyME8nSGFyZSUyMEludGVybmF0aW9uYWwlMjBBaXJwb3J0JTJDJTIwSUxfX19lX35wb3MuNDEuNzg4MTUxXy04Ny43NDExNTBfQ2hpY2FnbyUyME1pZHdheSUyMEFpcnBvcnQlMkMlMjBJTF9fX2VfJm1vZGU9RCZydG9wPTB+MH4wfg==).

When I tried using different addresses , the driving time would ***in most cases*** be calculated fine . . . however the ***distance is almost always higher*** than the one that I would get typing in the addresses manually into the Bing Map . . .

Is it the issue with the Bing Map API ? Maybe I should use the `getDistance` method in a different way ?

---

Although the distances are close to what Bing Map shows manually however not exactly the same . How come they are not the same ?

Thank You !

Comment: I checked it . . . i do not have enough reputation to say this but it appears that it is a bug with the api

Comment: Miles? Since when does bing use imperial units in it's API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use actual coordinates manually, the driving time seems to be identical given rounding of seconds, see [test link](http://www.bing.com/maps/#Y3A9NDEuODg1MDc4fi04Ny43NzQzNjYmbHZsPTExJnN0eT1yJnJ0cD1wb3MuNDEuOTc5ODA5Xy04Ny44ODIwNDJfNDEuOTc5ODA4ODA3MzczJTJDJTIwLTg3Ljg4MjA0MTkzMTE1MjNfX19lX35wb3MuNDEuNzg3MjIwXy04Ny43NDE2MDhfNDEuNzg3MjIwMDAxMjIwNyUyQyUyMC04Ny43NDE2MDc2NjYwMTU2X19fZV8mbW9kZT1EJnJ0b3A9MH4wfjB+). I get 35 minutes and your floored result is 34 minutes.

Now, about the distance. In the test link you can see it's 26.7 miles, whereas your code gives a result of 42.898 (you added the 'miles' unit there yourself!). Now, if you [convert your 26.7 miles to kilometers](https://www.google.fi/#q=26.7+miles+in+km), you get 42.9695. I would thus claim the result of .getDistance() is actually kilometers, not miles.

By looking at [Route api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701717.aspx) seems to confirm it:

> distanceUnit
>
> du
>
> Optional. The units to use for distance in the response.
>
> One of the following values:
>
> - Mile or mi
> - Kilometer or km [default]

So the numbers you get are pretty much accurate IMO.

Comment: I guess the "km" comment is correct. However, with all due respect, **the numbers although being close are not the same as if you try the same Bing Maps manually**. The question was : Where does Bing get those numbers ? Why are not they the same ?

Comment: @Buras um, manual numbers are rounded more than what java api gives. It would not make sense to show 4 digits to end user. The difference is smaller than the amount of digits shown when using manually. How could they be 100% equal if the accuracy is not the same? What do you expect manual number be in miles, if the distance is 42.898 km? 26.7 is what it should be.